# Android Drawing a Rectangle right to left (rtl)

Tags: android, android-canvas, draw, rect

I'm building a drawing app in android and I noticed a problem while drawing a rectangle. the rectangle should be drawn according to the syntax

```
new Rect(left, top, right, bottom)
```

now my logic works by taking the start point **(startX, startY)** and end point **(endX, endY)** and I draw using:

```
new Rect(startX,startY, endX, endY);
```

assuming the user is drawing from the top left corner to the bottom right.

**The Problem**

now the problems happens when the user tries to draw the rectangle form right to left or from bottom to top. working on the first problem (right to left):
it means the startX is now pointing to the right (rather than left). so the code will be trying to draw with this syntax now:

```
new Rect(right, top, left, bottom)
```

Which will fail to draw the rectangle.
In other words, startX is larger than endX which shouldn't be while drawing the rectangle.

**Resolution**

so I used the following code to check before drawing the rectangle:

```
int smallX,largeX,smallY,largeY;
if(startX>endX){    smallX=endX;    largeX=startX;  }else{  smallX=startX;  largeX=endX;    }
if(startY>endY){    smallY=endY;    largeY=startY;  }else{  smallY=startY;  largeY=endY;    }
rect = new Rect(smallX, smallY,largeX,largeY);
```

And that will ensure than the first parameter will always point to the left and the others are good as well.

My question here... Is there another way around to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, because Canvas is settted by coordinates and the coordinate (0,0) is top left and grow to bottom right, and the renderer follow that logic, start top left an go line after line to the bottom.